# Why can't I convert epoch time to a string?

Tags: go

I have the following program:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    now := time.Now().UnixNano() / int64(time.Millisecond)
    nowString := string(now)
    fmt.Println(nowString)
}
```

I'm expecting the epoch time to be printed as a string. Instead I get:

```
�
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Conversion to string **cannot** be done with string(now). Take the Tour of Go. Use fmt.Sprintf to convert numbers to strings or use time.Time.Format.

Comment: Most basic questions are answered within the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org) which only takes a few minutes to finish.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a lot of calculations which are not needed if you use `time`'s functions as exemplified here - https://gobyexample.com/time-formatting-parsing

Also. if all you need to do is to print an integer, you don't have to convert it to a string but simply use a format specifier like:

```
func main() {
    now := time.Now().UnixNano() / int64(time.Millisecond)
    //now is an int64 as you may have observed
    fmt.Printf("%d", now)
    //or even fmt.Println(now)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

main.go

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "time"

func main() {
    nanos := time.Now().UnixNano()
    fmt.Println(time.Unix(0, nanos))

    millis := nanos / 1000000
    fmt.Println(millis)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [strconv](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/).

> Package strconv implements conversions to and from string
> representations of basic data types.

In your case, for converting an [int64](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#int64) number to a [string](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#string), you may need to use [FormatInt](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#FormatInt) as below:

> *func FormatInt(i int64, base int) string*
>
> FormatInt returns the string representation of i in the given base,
> for 2 <= base <= 36. The result uses the lower-case letters 'a' to 'z'
> for digit values >= 10.

```
convertedString := strconv.FormatInt(YOUR_NUMBER, 10)
```

---

And Here is an example of [Epoch (https://gobyexample.com/epoch),](https://gobyexample.com/epoch) using the [time](https://golang.org/pkg/time/) package:

```
func main() {

    now := time.Now()
    secs := now.Unix()
    nanos := now.UnixNano()
    fmt.Println(now)

    millis := nanos / 1000000
    fmt.Println(secs)
    fmt.Println(millis)
    fmt.Println(nanos)

    fmt.Println(time.Unix(secs, 0))
    fmt.Println(time.Unix(0, nanos))
}
```

output:

```
$ go run epoch.go 
2012-10-31 16:13:58.292387 +0000 UTC
1351700038
1351700038292
1351700038292387000
2012-10-31 16:13:58 +0000 UTC
2012-10-31 16:13:58.292387 +0000 UTC
```